# BOM: binary output from Oracle xquery

Tags: xquery, byte-order-mark, osb

We need to write UTF-8 csv file from the OSB. To make Excel open it correctly we need to add BOM sequence EFBBBF at the beginning of the file. Is it possible to append binary data to the body, which in turn contains binary data in a form of binary-content?
If not, is it possible at least to write that sequence of bytes to the file?

Of course, non-Java solutions are more welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This "magic" sequence may be represented as `&#239;&#187;&#191;` but the issue with concatenating this "string" with binary-content obtained from NXSD transformation is still not resolved.